# Using doccano for Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis annotation

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, tools, annotation

Currently looking for a good tool to annotate sentences regarding aspects and their respective sentiment polarities.

I'm using SemEval Task 4 as a reference. The following is an example in the training dataset:

```
<sentence id="2005">
    <text>it is of high quality, has a killer GUI, is extremely stable, is highly expandable, is bundled with lots of very good applications, is easy to use, and is absolutely gorgeous.</text>
    <aspectTerms>
        <aspectTerm term="quality" polarity="positive" from="14" to="21"/>
        <aspectTerm term="GUI" polarity="positive" from="36" to="39"/>
        <aspectTerm term="applications" polarity="positive" from="118" to="130"/>
        <aspectTerm term="use" polarity="positive" from="143" to="146"/>
    </aspectTerms>
</sentence>
```

Can I easily use doccano for such a task? Or would I be better off using some other tool, such as brat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sequence labeling feature to annotate the text:

[image]